# Confluence - Access Activity Stream of Comala Workflows

Tags: java, confluence

We want to introduce [Comala Workflows](https://wiki.comalatech.com/display/CW/Comala+Workflows+Documentation+Home) in our Confluence to be compliant with [ISO 9001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9000#Contents_of_ISO_9001) (review and approve spaces/pages in Confluence).

### Task

If the page is exported from Confluence as pdf the current status of the page (to be reviewed, to be approved, approved) and the user which reviewed and approved the page should be visible at the head of the page. So I want to have a user macro or programmed (Java) macro which displays these informations.

### My Problem

I can't figure out how the [API of the Comala Workflows](https://wiki.comalatech.com/display/CW/API+Services) works. I want to access current workflow state and the users which did these changes.

I worked through the [Confluence Macro Tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/tutorials/macro-tutorials-for-confluence/creating-a-new-confluence-macro?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.atlassian.com%2Fconfdev%2Ftutorials%2Fmacro-tutorials-for-confluence%2Fcreating-a-new-confluence-macro) and the macro works fine in my Cunfluence test environment, but i can't even get the Comala Workflows example running - it seems that the tutorial is outdated (the [API documentation](https://wiki.comalatech.com/display/CW/API+Getting+Started) says I should use the `adhocapi` version 1.4.1 which is from 28-Feb-2013) and the usage of `BaseMacro` is deprecated in the Confluence documentation.

Furthermore I can't find any API documentation on how to access the workflow state of the page or how to initialize and use the services (like the `com.comalatech.workflow.StateService`).

**Has anybody used the public Comala Workflows API or does know how to access the workflow states (either in Java or in a User Macro)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roberto here, from Comalatech. We have made changes very recently that will allow you including the status and approval information in the exported PDF, so you may not need to create the user macro for what you want.

You are right on that the API documentation, is not up to date. We will look into it.

In any case, can you submit a ticket on https://comalatech.zendesk.com/ ? we can take it from there, as our support team does not monitor stackoverflow.